# How to get Spacy's SpanRuler to create non-empty ent_type_ attributes

Tags: python, spacy

I'm trying to get SpanRuler to dynamically convert a list of dictionaries into ent_types.
The following code incorrectly produces the output below:

Note: I've got PhraseMatcher working...was told SpanRuler would work more efficiently...damned if I can get it to work :
If anyone has experience with SpanRuler, much appreciation in advance

SpanRuler Output: incorrect

```
is 
a 
sentence 
with 
a 
the 
acronym 
AA    # Should produce the ent_type_ 'ACRO'
in 
it 
, 
its 
definition 
is 
Airplane GPE     # Should produce the ent_type_ 'DEF'
Agoraphobia GPE  # Should produce the ent_type_ 'DEF'
```

Incorrect Code:

```
from spacy.pipeline import SpanRuler

# Load the spaCy model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Add the SpanRuler to the pipeline, before the 'ner' component
if "span_ruler" not in nlp.pipe_names:
    ruler = nlp.add_pipe("span_ruler", before="ner")
else:
    ruler = nlp.get_pipe("span_ruler")

# Define patterns
terms = [
    {'ent': 'ACRO', 'patterns': [[{"LOWER": "aa"}]]},
    {'ent': 'DEF', 'patterns': [[{"LOWER": "airplane"}, {"LOWER": "agoraphobia"}]]}
]

# Add patterns to the ruler
for d in terms:
    for pattern in d['patterns']:
        ruler.add_patterns([{"label": d['ent'], "pattern": pattern}])

# Process the text with spaCy AFTER the ruler is set up
text = "This is a sentence with a the acronym AA in it, its definition is Airplane Agoraphobia"
doc = nlp(text)

# Print tokens and their entity labels
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.ent_type_)
```

Working code using PhraseMatcher

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Span

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

# Create a doc object by processing the text but without NER
doc = nlp.make_doc("This is a sentence with a the acronym AA in it, it's definition is Airplane Agoraphobia")

matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

# List of custom phrases to match
terms = [
    {'ent': 'ACRO', 'patterns': ['AA']},
    {'ent': 'DEF', 'patterns': ['Airplane Agoraphobia']}
]

# Add the patterns to the matcher
for d in terms:
    patterns = [nlp.make_doc(pattern) for pattern in d['patterns']]
    matcher.add(d['ent'], patterns)

# Find matches in the doc
matches = matcher(doc)

# Add the matched spans to a new list
custom_ents = [Span(doc, start, end, label=label) for label, start, end in matches]

# Run spaCy's NER
ner(doc)

# Combine the entities, prioritizing the custom entities
final_ents = []
seen_tokens = set()

# Add custom entities first
for ent in custom_ents:
    if any(token.i in seen_tokens for token in ent):
        continue
    final_ents.append(ent)
    seen_tokens.update(token.i for token in ent)

# Add spaCy's entities, but don't overwrite custom ones
for ent in doc.ents:
    if any(token.i in seen_tokens for token in ent):
        continue
    final_ents.append(ent)
    seen_tokens.update(token.i for token in ent)

doc.ents = final_ents

# Merging contiguous entities
with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    for ent in doc.ents:
        retokenizer.merge(ent)

# Print tokens and their entity labels
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.ent_type_)
```